# Creating PowerPoint 2010 add-in - and adding to Quick Access Toolbar

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have been working on an add-in with some short-cuts for PowerPoint 2010.
I am able to make the add-in "tab" so that I can access my macros from PowerPoint after installing the add-in.

However, I cannot add the macros to my Quick Access Toolbar, or otherwise create shortcuts. 
This creates a need to use a very extensive key combination to access the add-in shortcuts, eliminating part of the rationale behind them.

Is there any way to make PowerPoint macros that I can then link to the Quick Access Toolbar?